# Errors when finding local extrema using stationary point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

E.g.

$f(x)=x^2-3x+2$

$f'(x)=2x-3$

For a stationary point

$f'(x)=0$

$2x-3=0$

$x=\frac{3}{2} $

To find maximum and minimum

We can find it by checking whether $f'(0)$ and $f'(4)$ are positive or negative

(just with number greater and lesser than $\frac{3}{2}$)

We get $f'(0)=-3$ and $f'(4)=5$

Negative then positive, therefore it is a local minimum.

//

BUT here's come up with my problem:

The most accurate way to find those two sign should be $\frac{3}{2}^-$ and $\frac{3}{2}^+$

Cause we can barely see the trend with the smallest change

But the derivatives of $\frac{3}{2}^-$ and $\frac{3}{2}^+$  should be equal to $\frac{3}{2}$.

This is because by the differentiability of a function, if a function is differentiable,

$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ = $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0^-} \frac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ = $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0^+} \frac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$

So $f'(\frac{3}{2})$ = $f'(\frac{3}{2}^+)$ = $f'(\frac{3}{2}^-)$ = $0$

Where is the problem of my calculation?

Comment: How are you defining $\frac{3}{2}^{-}$, $\frac{3}{2}^{+}$?

Comment: I don't see a problem. $f'(\frac32^-)=0^-$ and  $f'(\frac32^+)=0^+$.

Comment: Approaching $\frac{3}{2}$ from left side and right side.
Very close to $\frac{3}{2}$ but not equal to.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But the limit at the third sentences counting from bottom.
Doesn't that limit suggested that the derivatives of  three of them are $0$ ?
Or did I have any misunderstand ?

Comment: Your reasoning is a little like: I have a number which is positive or negative. If I multiply it by zero, I get zero, so the sign is gone, how come ?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing $\frac{3}{2}^+$ by $\frac{3}{2}+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and you should have the result you're looking for. The expression will never be equal but the limit might be.

Comment: I know that if $ϵ$ is larger like $2$ or $-2$, then I can actually obtain the result I want.
But for more accurate shouldn't the $ϵ$ approaching to $0$?
Maybe $ϵ$ equal to the concept of infinitesimal?
Then would I obtain still zero or the result I'm looking for?

Comment: The infinitesimal $\epsilon$ is always larger than zero, so you would obtain the result you're looking for. Note the difference between limit and actual value. $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ but $\frac{1}{n}$ is never zero for any real n.